# Why module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying this simple tutorial to try UI Bootstrap:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together
But I am running into two problems.

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' at  ui-bootstrap-1.3.3.js:5:0

This is the first problem. I have not edited anything in the file, yet it says unexpected token for the very first line `<!DOCTYPE html>`

And the other one is as below:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I saw answers to all the related questions, some of them suggesting to include the other dependencies while other suggesting to make sure of the order of the dependencies. Tried everything but no joy.

Below is my html and js code. Please have a look
**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
            @import "css/bootstrap.css";
            @import "css/style.css";
        </style>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-1.3.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

  <div class="text-center">
    <p>Example of Angular and the normal Bootstrap JavaScript components</p>
    <p class="text-success">This will work</p>
  </div>

  <h2>Buttons</h2>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="bigData.breakfast" btn-checkbox>
      Breakfast
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="bigData.lunch" btn-checkbox>
      Lunch
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="bigData.dinner" btn-checkbox>
      Dinner
    </label>
  </div>

  <pre><code>{{ bigData | json }}</code></pre>

  <h2>Collapse</h2>

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    Toggle Panel
  </a>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div collapse="isCollapsed">
      <div class="panel-body">Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <pre><code>{{ isCollapsed }}</code></pre>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

  // BUTTONS ======================

  // define some random object
  $scope.bigData = {};

  $scope.bigData.breakfast = false;
  $scope.bigData.lunch = false;
  $scope.bigData.dinner = false;

  // COLLAPSE =====================
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;

});
```

Not sure what's going wrong.

**Edit**
Version details area as follows
Bootstrap v3.3.6

angular
angular-animate
angular-touch
all are having version AngularJS v1.5.3

Comment: Seems like a bug in ui bootstrap

Comment: for the second error you need to install ui-bootstrap and include it in your project.

Comment: @neha soni install? Isn't just downloading the js file and adding it via script tag enough? Is there any standalone installation kind of thing?

Comment: Yes its the same. My mistake. You can try adding a different ui-bootstrap file, means download from somewhere else.

Comment: Does ui.bootstrap.js load? could you see that js file from chrome debugger?

Comment: what is your angular.js version?

Comment: @Durgpal Singh it's 1.5.3

Comment: seems like `ui-bootstrap-1.3.3` file is not getting added. can you please make sure or provide plunker for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure `ui-bootstrap-1.3.3` is loaded correctly in your app.**

Please find working plunker below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/evG4XQ9ih9Cx0d1WF6YU?p=preview

Comment: I found a quick fix. It seems the file when downloaded on my system is not working.
But if I am referring the link: `<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>` it works. So for now I have just replaced uibootstarp import line. Rest of the imports are as they were

Comment: Glad your problem is resolved. Please correct the answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: But can you plesae help, why the checkboxes or the collapse are not working as expected. On the tutorial website, if we check/uncheck any item, the same is instantly reflected in the json output.  Similarly for collapse, the output is changing to true/false but the content is not getting collapsed here, but on the tutorial website its working perfectly fine. Any idea?

Comment: Please find the updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/evG4XQ9ih9Cx0d1WF6YU?p=preview Go thorgh the documentation. they have very well documentation

Comment: Its still the same. Changes are not reflected there.
Also collapse is not working??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116781/discussion-between-vikas-prasad-and-varit05).

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file.

add this file in your page.

see example [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2LbaCoHKHKzifeL5Hny?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in a legacy application (AngularJS 1.3), it was because I put `angular-ui-bootstrap` to `bower.js` rather than `package.js`.

After I put it to `package.js`, ran `npm install`, copied to some source directory, and added to imports, it worked.

```
import '../js/dependencies/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min'
```

It is probably not the right way to do it, though.
I think it should be imported from `bower_modules`.

```
import '../bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap/???';
```

But, the Bower hosting does not work anymore and an attempt to install through `bower install` fails with HTTP 502.

Also, what's weird, it worked **unless** I registered a provider:

```
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function ($tooltipProvider) { ...
```

This way, Angular started complaining that `'$tooltipProvider'` is not known.

Hope this helps, although I do not know much about the old AngularJS, so take it as potentially mediocre solution.